# OpenCV: how can I detect a closed contour consisting of dots & segments?

Tags: opencv, object-detection, shapes

I want to use OpenCV to detect an imperfect elliptic contour in binary images. Unfortunately, the elliptic contour consists of separate large dots with even larger gaps (of up to 25 pixels) between them.

I have tried OpenCV contour detection, but it doesn't work. It only marks the locations of individual dots instead of generating one enclosure for the contour.

How can I detect the contour using OpenCV? Please help. [Here's a sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxEAu.png)

My final goal is to fit the dotted loop with an ellipse. Other dots nearby are noise data points. I have tried to get the contour centers for each dot or cluster of dots and put the xy coordinates of those centers into an array. I hope that FitEllipse will capture only the contour centers forming that loop. But when I do the FitEllipse, I got an exception "Emgu.CV.Util.CvException: 'OpenCV: n >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S)' "

```
private void btnGO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Mat pic = new Mat();
    pic = CvInvoke.Imread("test image.png", 
    Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ImreadModes.Grayscale);              

    VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours= new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();

    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();           

    CvInvoke.FindContours(pic, contours, hierarchy, 
    Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RetrType.Tree, 
    Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);

    Moments moments = new Moments();            

    List<Point> contourCentersList = new List<Point>();

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.Size; i++)
    {
        int x;
        int y;
                            
        moments = CvInvoke.Moments(contours[i]);

        if (moments.M00 == 0)
        continue;

        x = Convert.ToInt32(moments.M10 / moments.M00);
        y = Convert.ToInt32(moments.M01 / moments.M00);

        ContourCentersList.Add(new Point(x, y));
    }

    Mat contourCenters = new Mat();
    contourCenters.SetTo(contourCentersList.ToArray());

    RotatedRect ellipse = new RotatedRect();

    ellipse = CvInvoke.FitEllipse(contourCenters);  
}
```

Comment: Please provide you code. This would make it easier to provide a good answer. You need a generous connectivity condition allowing large gaps. Would it be sufficient to detect the bounding box of white areas in the image for your purpose? Or are you after polygons enclosing the "ellipse".

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain a contour you can pre-process the image to get the not connected areas connected.

For this purpose you can for example apply blur and then threshold the image.

Below your image and the result of applying blur and threshold:

[image: before] [image: after]